# Placement of 'Little'

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position, intensifying-adverbs

According to the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/little_3), 'little' as an adverb could mean:

> not much; only slightly

Is there a preference among these sentences?

> - He *little* helped his friends.
> - He helped *little* his friends.
> - He helped his friends *little*.

Comment: As implied by @StoneyB's answer, the overwhelming preference would be to forget about using "little" ***at all*** in any such construction. All these variations would have been credible a century or two ago, but none would arise in natural spoken English today. The closest that *would* be acceptable is *"He helped his friends **very little**"*, but I can't for the life of me explain why simply inserting the word "very" has such an effect on acceptability.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I believe the second one was ungrammatical a century ago, as it has an adverb between the verb and the direct object. I suspect the fact that you didn't recognize this shows how little bare *little* is used these days.

Comment: @Peter Shor: Good point. I did find [this from 1915](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PUA5AAAAIAAJ&q=%22helps+little+his%22&dq=%22helps+little+his%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U_PVUPnAGfCU0QXJgYHgBA&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ) *This man who is wholly free may will that which helps little his life*. But it's a pretty weird construction all round, and I couldn't easily find any more examples, so I think you're right. As you say, my lack of an "ear" for such things is probably just another indication of how rare bare *little* is.

Answer (score 4):

[Tennyson](http://www.artofeurope.com/tennyson/ten4.htm) writes

> It little profits that an idle king...

So your first sentence is not an unheard of construction.

> He little helps his friends.

This gives the suggestion that he provides help infrequently. It also sounds formal and literary.

> He helps little his friends.

This sentence sounds like he's trying to make his friends smaller.

> He helps his friends little.

This sentence could mean infrequently; it also sounds like he's just generally not of much help. It is less formal-sounding too.

This last one, I think we've all agreed, is probably the most common way of expressing what you are trying to say, although gmcgath is right in the comments, where he says that

> He helps his friends very little.

is more usual.

Comment: The Tennyson quote was exactly the first one to come to my mind as well.  I agree that “to help little” sorely risks construing *little* to be a verb.

Answer (score 3):

Bare *little*, as an adverb, is uncommon in US speech; it’s been largely replaced by *not much*.

You will encounter it more often in written discourse of a fairly formal register. There is a distinct preference for placing it immediately before the word it modifies:

- *The little-used “little” has been largely replaced by “not much”*, OR
- *“Little” is little used today*, BUT
- <sup>?</sup>*”Little” is used little today* has a distinct donnish ring even in an academic register. However, as others have noted, *very little* here is more acceptable.

It’s most comfortably accommodated in sentence-initial or -final position:

- *Little as he had helped his friends, they valued his attempt*, AND
- *Little did he know what awaited him in the following months*, AND
- *He had helped his friends little*; BUT
- <sup>?</sup>*He had little helped his friends* AND
- <sup>?</sup>*He knew little what awaited him in the following months* are “literary”.

I suspect that what’s involved in all of these is conflict with the more frequent use of bare *little* as an adjective or noun, and of *a little* as an adverb with a slightly different sense. To avoid arresting the flow we have come to shy away from placing bare *little* in positions where any of these might be in play.

Comment: haha - I should have read all the answers and comments before posting my comment to the question! Obviously we all recognise a *big* problem with "bare" *little*, that magically goes away when it's preceded by *very*. I'll leave the comment, since it was what I thought at the time - but for my money you've nailed the explanation in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it with *a*, as in the second definition in the *Advanced Learners Dictionary*: “He helped his friends a little.”

Comment: Actually, I want to use 'little' in the spirit of "Little did he help his friends."

Comment: That's strange on its own. It depends on exactly what it is you're trying to say.

Comment: I want it to mean that 'He hardly helped his friends.'

Comment: Then if you want to use _little_, it has to be _He helped his friends very little_.

Comment: I think *He helped his friends little,* works as well.

Comment: @Peter Shor. Perhaps, but I just can't imagine anyone saying it.

Comment: @Barrie: it's grammatical, unlike the other two. [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+worked+little%2Che+worked+very+little&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) seems to show a dramatic decline of *little* as an adverb over the past few decades, so I suspect you might it in a book written some time ago. It does sound quite stilted.

Comment: "He helped his friends little" is technically correct but sounds odd. "He helped his friends very little" would be a more usual thing to say.

Comment: @PeterShor I do not believe the version without *a* should stand, because it gardenpaths you into thinking that *little* is somehow [a verb in the bare infinitive following *help*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95032/2085), as in *to help someone little something else*. Of course that makes no sense, so the whole construct is quite confusing, and to my mind should therefore be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Shor in the comments.

*Little* without being preceded by *a* would mean *almost none*. I had little money in my account = I had almost no money in my account.

So, *He helped his friends little* would give the sense you are looking for.

I might also add that the same rule goes with *few* and *a few*.

- Few women have led troops in battle. (Almost none)
- A few women have led troops in battle. (Some)

Answer (score 0):

"He helped his friend little" goes well.

Comment: Without _a_ it sounds quite funny.