# to know or know

Tags: verbs, bare-infinitive

One of my English friends has written to me:

> A teacher can receive no greater gift than **to know** he has had a positive influence on his students.

Here is my question: Why has he written ***to*** know with a *to* in front of *know* there? I myself think the sentence should  instead be like this, without the *to* part:

> A teacher can receive no greater gift than **know** he has had a positive influence on his students."

I think the use of *to know* there is wrong. Is it?

Comment: I can't give you the nuts-and-bolts reason but I can assure you that "to know" is correct.  You can also replace "to know" with "knowing".  ***"A teacher can receive no greater gift than knowing he has had a positive influence on his students."***

Comment: You are wrong. May you should tell us why you think so?

Answer (score 2):

A bare infinitive cannot serve as a noun phrase the way a *to*-infinitive or an *-ing* form acting as a gerund can:

- His best idea was **going** home early.
- His best idea was **to go** home early.
- His best idea was ***go** home early.

Just like:

- **Going** home early was his best idea.
- **To go** home early was his best idea.
- ***Go** home early was his best idea.

The starred ones are ungrammatical, as is your revision of your correspondent’s sentence, and for the same reason.

Comment: Which is to say the second option should read "A teacher can receive no greater gift than knowing he has had a positive influence on his students.

Comment: It's not as clear-cut as this. There are plenty of Google hits for {"best thing you can do is" + bare infinitive}. This is probably an ellipted form of {"best thing you can do is" + to-infinitive}, which I think is always available, but I think it's the inclusion of _do_ that licenses the ellipsis.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought of that, and since it can only work with *can* or other modals, I’m convinced that it the modal applies there to the second verb as well.

Comment: _To_ is deleted from many infinitives when governed by what are called "small verbs" by some. These are verbs like _let, make, have_ that occur in constructions as auxiliaries and have had most of their lexical meaning bleached out of them. The construction Edwin mentions is a repetition of the unmarked _do_ following the modal. And, yes, it's the use of the proverb _do_ that licenses the following verb; it works without modals, as in _The last thing I did was (to) sell the car_, with optional _to_.

Comment: @JohnLawler The [sensory verbs also suppress the *to* particle](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/95032), but I don’t know why.

Comment: Looks like you should publish. :-)