# Subject -verb agreement OR

Tags: idioms, verb-agreement

"One need look no further.." Shouldn't it be "One needs look no further.."-

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is fine as it is, because *need* is a semi-modal verb. However,

> One doesn't need to look any further,

would also work.

In negative sentences (and this sentence is negative because of the words *no further*), *need* and *dare* can be modal auxiliary verbs, behaving like the modal auxiliary verbs *must, can, will, would* etc. They are not conjugated, and do not take *to* after them.

Consider:

> One must look further,
> One need look no further,
> One dare not look further.

In positive sentences, *need* and *dare* cannot behave this way; they are conjugated and need to be followed by *to*.

> One needs to look further.
> He dares to look further.

See [this webpage](https://www.grammaring.com/the-semi-modal-need)

Answer (score -2):

I would generally regard "one", in this sense, as being 3rd-person singular.  If that is the case then "needs" is the proper verb form.

(There are no doubt those who will argue that "one" isn't 3rd-person singular here, but I doubt that they could convince me.)

Comment: This argues that need, when used as a modal, does not inflect: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95031/usage-of-infinitives-in-this-sentence/95032#95032

Answer (score -5):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/need

When used as a main verb:

You need to study.
You don't need to study.
Do you need to study?
Don't you need to study?

When used as a helping verb:

We need go there.
We needn't go there. (Don't say, "We don't need....")

Note: Some people use "We need to go there" in affirmative; and "We need not go there" in negatives.

Comment: For those enjoying down-voting: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/dare-and-need
Dare and need sometimes behave like main verbs with -s inflection… Louisa doesn’t need to know.
Does Paul need to go now? Paul needs to go.
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/need_1: Need as a transitive: I need a drink. Do you need anything? She needs to rest. You don’t need to worry. 
https://www.grammaring.com/the-semi-modal-need: Do you have a minute?
I don't need to be told that I should lose weight.Do you need to use the hairdryer?
You will need to work harder.